# How to convert uA/mA to uA in each lines of csv file using c shell?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, csv-simple

I have a *.csv file as bellow. What I want to do is converting all units to one unit (uA). Anyone can help to do this in c shell??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code, it now works fine to me.

```
# Add a space between result and unit
sed -e 's/mA/ mA/g' -e 's/uA/ uA/g' myfile.csv

#Convert
    awk -F" " '{\
    if ($4 == "mA"){\
        $3*=1000;\
        $4 = "uA";}\
    else\
        $3=$3;\
    }1' OFS=" " myfile.csv >> new_myfile.csv
```

Comment: FS and OFS default to space so you don't need to set that, and awk can handle this without the separate sed: `awk '$3~/mA$/{ sub(/mA$/,"",$3); $3=($3*1000)"uA"} 1'`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's worth doing in csh, but here's a crappy "bash" solution:

```bash
cat foo.csv | while IFS='' read -r line; do
    multiplicand="$(
        echo "$line" | 
        perl -pe 's/^.*?([\.0-9]+)mA$/\1/g'
    )"
    echo "$line" | \
    perl -pe 's/^(.*?)'"$(
        echo "$multiplicand" | 
        perl -pe 's/\./\\./g'
    )"'mA$/${1}'"$(
        bc -l <<< "$multiplicand"*1000 2>/dev/null | 
        perl -pe 's/\.0+//g'
    )"'uA/g'
done
```

Comment: Thanks Jan Kyu! I have tried and also edited your code but it didn't work for me. I am trying a new code with 'awk' command and if-else statement , and now my work can be done.